# How to access NGINX http server, running on my computer, with the public ip address of that computer

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker-compose

I put together this NodeJS React+Vite MySQL NGINX app and docker-composed it, so now it runs on localhost:80 
Now how do I configure NGINX in a way so this website can be accessed through the internet with just my computer's public IP address?

This is the docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  client:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb

    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'register'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'

    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - ./server/init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    expose:
      - 3306

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    
volumes:
  db:
```

This is the nginx.conf file

```
events {}
http {

  upstream frontend {
    server client:8080;
  } 

  upstream backend {
    server server:5000;
  } 

  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend/;
    }

    location /api { 
      proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }

  }
  
}
```